# Get value from RDPMC using Go

Tags: go, assembly

I am running an Ubuntu server VM on VMware on my Fedora system and I would like to retrieve my host's TSC value. According to VMware, I can do that by executing RDPMC 0x10000. This works using inline assembly in C++ but now I need to do the same in go.

Basically, the logic of my code resides in two files. In a .s file I have this:

```
#include "textflag.h"

// func rdPmcTsc() uint64
TEXT ·rdPmcTsc(SB), NOSPLIT, $0
    MOVL $0x10000, CX
    RDPMC
    RET
```

Which I link into a .go file like so:

```
//go:nosplit
func rdPmcTsc() uint64
```

I have been debugging this on VScode and, looking at the values in the AX and DX registers, it seems the assembly code works as intended. However, once I need to use the value in Go, it transforms values around 25Ti into others around 8000 and other similar errors.
I have been looking around for long, but I haven't found any reasonable explanation as to why this could happen. And, to my best knowledge, it seems that the way I am trying to get the RDPMC 0x10000 value is how it should be done in Go.

If anyone knows how to get the correct return value in Go, knows why it may not be working or anything of that sort, it would be great.

Comment: I don't use *go* but I do find it special to see `MOVL $0x10000, CX` using the 16-bit register CX that can't contain the 0x10000. Don't know if the `L` in `MOVL` resolves that on its own. Also in the debugger, make sure to look at the values for **E**AX and **E**DX (so not at AX and DX).

Comment: @SepRoland The Go assembler distinguishes operand size by suffix, not register name.  Go's `CX` can stand for any of `cl`, `cx`, `ecx`, and `rcx`, depending on operand size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to fix it. It turns out the result needs to be stored before RET in order for Go to retrieve it. Also, the 32 bits of rax and rdx had to be combined to get the full TSC result. The following assembler code fixed it:

```
#include "textflag.h"

// func rdPmcTsc() uint64
TEXT ·rdPmcTsc(SB), NOSPLIT, $0
    MOVL $0x10000, CX
    RDPMC
    SHLQ $32, DX       // Shift the higher bits in rdx
    ORQ DX, AX         // Combine the 2 registers for the 64 bits result
    MOVQ AX, ret+0(FP) // Store the result
    RET
```

Comment: Yes, Go uses its own inefficient calling convention where even return values are passed on the stack.  I thought I read they were going to change that for some ISAs, but apparently haven't yet.  And yes, `rdtsc` / `rdpmc` do exactly the same thing in 32 and 64-bit mode, so you have to waste instructions recombining their split outputs if you want the full value, not just the low 32 bits.  In this case you could instead just do two 32 bit stores, but then the caller would have a store-forwarding stall when it did a 64-bit load.